# Is Direct3D 12 supported on Windows 10 Mobile (phone)?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, direct3d12

Is Direct3D 12 supported on Windows 10 Mobile (phone)? I've recently upgrade my personal project to Direct3D 12 under the impression that it runs on all versions of Windows 10 Universal Apps.  My phone ran my old Direct3D 11.1 code just fine, but D3D12CreateDevice() fails with the error that the specified feature level (11_0, 11_1, 12_0, or 12_1) or interface (ID3D12Device) is not supported.  Am I doing something wrong, or is D3D12 really not supported on phones?  If it isn't supported, will it ever be?  I don't mind just developing on PC for now, but I'd rather know now it will never be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899228(v=vs.85).aspx says:

> Direct3D 12 provides four main benefits 
>   [...], and **cross-platform** development for a
>   Windows 10 device (PC, tablet, console or phone).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899118(v=vs.85).aspx says:

> To program with Direct3D 12, you need these components:
>
> A hardware platform with a Direct3D 12-compatible GPU
>
> Display drivers that support the Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) 2.0

Comment: I think "Display Drivers" is key here as most of the DirectX11 hardware can run DirectX12 stuff already.  At least, I'm hoping that's the case because I would like my Adreno 430 GPU on my Lumia 950XL (which supports DX11.1) to get an upgrade to support the DX12 app I'm writing...

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses, especially the links.  I didn't even think of looking up support for my phone's GPU instead of the phone itself.  I also have a Lumia 950.  I ran my test app on it after reading your comment and it turns out that mine is also an Adreno 430 GPU.  Unfortunately, according to Qualcomm's website, the 430 doesn't support D3D12.  We'll need to wait for a Windows Phone with at least a 625. See [https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon/gpu-specifications#](https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon/gpu-specifications#)